# excel addin workbook_open procedure not firing

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel addin which creates some menu items in the workbook_open procedure. However it doesn't seem to fire all the time and I need to manually run it in the vba editor. I've posted a sample below. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set App = Application

    'Avoid placing multiple menus on worksheet.
    Dim Counter As Integer
    For Counter = 1 To Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Count
        If Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Item(Counter).Caption = "Investment Database" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next Counter

    'Add Investment Database menu to main menu bar and populate with buttons.
    Dim newMenu As CommandBarPopup
    Dim btnQuery As CommandBarButton
    Dim btnEditQuery As CommandBarButton
    Dim btnFillQuery As CommandBarButton
    Dim btnRequest As CommandBarButton
    Dim btnRequestWS As CommandBarButton
    Dim btnRequestAll As CommandBarButton
    Dim btnDatabaseUpload As CommandBarButton

    Set newMenu = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, , , , True)
    newMenu.Caption = "Investment Database"

    Set btnQuery = newMenu.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
    btnQuery.Caption = "Generate Query..."
    btnQuery.OnAction = "Load_Generate_Query"
    btnQuery.FaceId = 599
```

Comment: Are events enabled? And you're sure the `Exit Sub` isn't being executed? What debugging have you done?

Comment: how can i debug this? i just know it works fine when i execute it manually in the wba editor. I have this line in my code `Public WithEvents App As Application`

Comment: Use of `Debug.Print` is one option.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328366/8488913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328366/8488913)